# OpenVPN: Some users are having "TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds"

Tags: ssl, openvpn, openssl

I have an OpenVPN server (setup using [Pritunl](https://github.com/pritunl/pritunl) with its default settings), everything's working fine for all users except for some of them (could reproduce it with only one client) not being able to connect to the server. I am getting the following output on the server:

```
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [Fedora EPEL patched] [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Apr 26 2018
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.06
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=1
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 192.168.225.1/24 broadcast 192.168.225.255
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 /sbin/ip -6 addr add fd00:c0a8:e100::1/64 dev tun0
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 setsockopt(IPV6_V6ONLY=0)
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 UDPv6 link local (bound): [AF_INET6][undef]:12941
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 UDPv6 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:18 2019 Initialization Sequence Completed
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:02:19 2019 COM> SUCCESS: bytecount interval changed
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:04:40 2019 105.x.xx.79 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:04:40 2019 105.x.xx.79 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:04:46 2019 105.x.xx.79 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
[restless-waters-9695] Mon Jan 28 15:04:46 2019 105.x.xx.79 NOTE: --mute triggered...
```

What's the cause of this? Knowing that this particular user is able to connect to another Pritunl instance of an older version (**OpenVPN 2.4.4**) and this new one is using **OpenVPN 2.4.6**. How to pinpoint the issue and what's the course of action for now?

Comment: Your ULA prefix is not randomly generated. This may cause a variety of problems in the future, or possibly even now. Renumber ASAP.